# How to generate 5 different random number in asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

How to generate 5 different random number in textbox by only 1 button？

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int num = r.Next();      
            TextBox1.Text = num.ToString();
            TextBox2.Text = num.ToString();
            TextBox3.Text = num.ToString();
            TextBox4.Text = num.ToString();
            TextBox5.Text = num.ToString();
        }
```

I understand with this will only get same number, but is there any way to get different number?

Comment: Repeat `r.Next()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short example with randomizer initialization

```
    static void Example()
    {
          var textBoxes = new List<TextBox> { Textbox1, Textbox2, Textbox3, Textbox4, Textbox5 };
          // GUID will produce better randomization
          var rand = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());        
          foreach (var textBox in textBoxes)
                textBox.Text = rand.Next().ToString();
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just put r.Next() in loop like below example:

```
    string printmsg = string.Empty;
    int[] x = new int[5];
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        x[i] = r.Next();
        printmsg += x[i] + ",";
    }
    lblMsg.Text = printmsg.Substring(0, printmsg.Length-1);
```

And then use it in array or string or different textboxes as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You can add every generated number to List. Then check contains or not.

```
                    Random r = new Random();
                    var list = new List<int>(5);
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                    {
                        var num = r.Next(5);
                        if (!list.Contains(num)) //If not add to list 
                        {
                            list.Add(num);
                        }
                        else //If contains return back and generate again.
                        {
                            i--; 
                        }
                    }
                  //It will more effective if you convert this section into loop. 
                    Textbox1.Text = list[0].ToString();
                    Textbox2.Text = list[1].ToString();
                    Textbox3.Text = list[2].ToString();
                    Textbox4.Text = list[3].ToString();
                    Textbox5.Text = list[4].ToString();
```